# How to use EXIF.py in Django photologue to extract GPSInfo from images and display it in google map

Tags: django, google-maps, gps, exif, photologue

I am using Django-photologue this app to display a photo gallery, which is quite nice. But what I want to do further is extract out the GPSInfo from each image and display it on the website (or more advanced, display it in google map). I am quite a newbie to Django, so don't know how to proceed.

The way I am doing the gallery is from [Django Photologue Upload Photo Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20304387/django-photologue-upload-photo-example).

If you can show me some details, like how to override the models, views, urls, that would be great. And if you can suggest another app to incorporate the google map API,I really appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Django-photologue's documentation](https://django-photologue.readthedocs.org/en/3.1/index.html) has some examples showing how you can override the admin, views, urls and models. If you try these examples, they can give you some ideas for creating your own customisations.

I am not sure how to best use EXIF.py, as I have never used it myself!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I am learning how to override them, still need some understanding of using models, forms and views.